# What is the name of the anti-pattern of using a js object/dictionary/map to implement an array/vector

Tags: arrays, json, dictionary, anti-patterns

*For ease of notation, I will use JSON in the following, though the anti-pattern can be programmed in many languages*

Let's say that I have a sensible JSON such as

```
{
    "SomeProperty": "SomeValue",
    "SomeOtherProperty": 42,
    "Items": [
        "ValueOfItem0", "ValueOfItem1"
    ]
}
```

It has simple entries and an array of items. An alternative way of representing the  data, which I think is an anti-pattern and for which I search the name is

```
{
    "someProperty": "someValue",
    "someOtherProperty": 42,
    "Item0": "valueOfItem0",
    "Item1": "valueOfItem1",
    "NumberOfItems": 2  
}
```

**Instead of by the array, the items are kept 'together' by the keys, which a consumer of the anti-pattern JSON would need to predict**. For this reason, the `NumberOfItems` property has been added, though by using a TryGet-like technique, the property can be made obsolete. Why would anyone do this? Limitations of the serializer.

---

Comments:
My search has revealed nothing. The sort-of opposite direction is the ["Arrject"](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/arrject), therefore my humble suggestion for the described anti-pattern, if yet unnamed, would be "Orray", a name already used by Star Wars.